# How to add vertical scrollbar to combobox programatically

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I am using silverlight and my combobox is like this:

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
```

Suppose it already contains Items which are visible only on clicking the combobox.

I want add a vertical scrollbar(or slider) programatically when it shows its items. Is there any inbuilt property for this in silverlight or do I need to use scrollbar or slider for it?

Answer (score 2):

There is an inbuilt property of `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollbarVisibility`. Set its value to `Visible`.

For more read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticalscrollbarvisibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: but who will be th e hcild of whom ? cb is child or scrollviewer is child ?

Comment: scrollviewer will be the child of cb.

Comment: I also have ot implemnt SelectionChanged event on combo. How i will do that because the items are on scrollbar now ? could you please write a piece of code explainign more ?

Comment: and "children property do not exist for  "cb".  so cb.Children(scrollBar); will not work in silverlight

Comment: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/217952-missing-combobox-vertical-scroll-bar-in-c%23-on-windows-7/  I used this trick.

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing the dropdownheight property.

```
cb.DropDownHeight = cb.ItemHeight * 5;
```

This is to view only 5 items at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Properties:

[image]

And set your specified height here.